# Load data from core data to display on collection view

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have two view controllers (vc1 and vc2). On vcTwo, when I add a game, I save the item using core data. The item should be displayed immediately on vcOne from a collection view. But the collection view does not load the data immediately even with `collectionView.reloadData`. I have to restart the app in order to see the last added item on the collection view. How could I make it happen.

```
var game: GameMo?
var gamesMo: [GameMo]? = []
var fetchRequestController : NSFetchedResultsController<GameMo>!

extension ViewControllerOne: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    func fetechRequest (){
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<GameMo>(entityName: "Game")

      fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "win", ascending: true)]

       if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate){
            let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

            // fetch result controller
            fetchRequestController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
            fetchRequestController.delegate = self

            do{
                try fetchRequestController.performFetch()

                if let fetchedObjects = fetchRequestController.fetchedObjects {
                    gamesMo = fetchedObjects


                    print(fetchRequest)
                }
            }catch{
                fatalError("Failed to fetch entities: \(error)")
            }
        }

    }
```

ViewController One

```
class ViewControllerTwo: UIViewController {
     var game: GameMo?
       func saveToCoreData(){
            guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
            game = GameMo(context: appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext)
            game?.gameOutcome = gameOutcome.text
            game?.goal = Int32(goal.text ?? "0") ?? 0
            game?.rivalGoal = Int32(rivalGoal.text ?? "0") ?? 0
    print("Saving data")
            appDelegate.saveContext()
            delegate?.reloadCollectionViewData()
        }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show any save operation.

Comment: Just added the save operation from the second view controller .

Comment: Try to call `fetchRequest()` of VC1 after the line `appDelegate.saveContext()` in the `saveToCoreData()` of VC2 (and fix the typo in `fetechRequest()`).

Comment: Worked. Was so simple I did not even thought about it.

Comment: How could I accept your answer ? where to click.

Comment: I am glad that it worked. Just give me a minute, I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `fetchRequest()` of VC1 after the line `appDelegate.saveContext()` in the `saveToCoreData()` function of VC2.